# Redmine - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Tracker with 'id'=0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am learning about [redmine](https://www.redmine.org/). I am trying to add [RedmineReminderEmail](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReminderEmails) feature. I am following doc, It didn't work in my case.

Here is the error that I am getting on executing the given command

```
$ bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV="production" 
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Tracker with 'id'=0
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
/home/rishikant/redmine/app/models/mailer.rb:382:in `reminders'
/home/rishikant/redmine/lib/tasks/reminder.rake:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/rishikant/redmine/app/models/mailer.rb:433:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/home/rishikant/redmine/lib/tasks/reminder.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:send_reminders
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I didn't understand why it is happening. Please give your valuable suggestion to fix this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an issue in your production database where tracker_id = 0 ? Your data may be corrupted.